# adb devices empty list

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I have problem with installing android development environment. I do following:

1) I installed the openjdk

2) download eclipse and sdk from developer.anroid.com site

3) type lsusb in shell and know vendor id: 10d6:0c02

4) create 51-android.rules in /etc/udev/rules.d folder:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0c02", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

5) and i edit the adb_usb.ini file, i add the 0x0c02 string

6) I enable debugging on my device

6) i run adb kill-server and adb start server and run adb devices and i get empty list

What is wrong? My pc is HP Envy 4 1055er and ubuntu 13.04 os. Please help me.

Comment: usb debugging is enabled in your android device ?

Comment: what android OS you are using ? probably latest andoid needs adb version 1.0.31.

Comment: Thank you for your help and attention, i just confusing the productId with the vendorId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're confusing the ProductId with the VendorID. Try adding 0x10d6 to the files instead of 0x0c02

Comment: Thank you, i really confusing it.